# Auto fill up text fields based on selected value in dropdown

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

I have a text field 'Brand' and one dropdown. The dropdown shows a productcodes from my database. So if i choose a selected value from the dropdown, the text field "Brand" will automatically print the info about the product based on the id of productcode.

So what i tried is, when there's a changes in the dropdown the text field will print or show a value based on the id of the selected value.
This is my PRS.php

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script>
  function getState(val) {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ff.php",
    data:'productid='+val,
    success: function(data){
      $("#brandss").val(data);
    }
    });
  }
  </script>


<td><select name="drpcode" onchange="getState(this.value)" class="form-control name_list"><?php $drp = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT productcode FROM products"); while ($dp = mysqli_fetch_array($drp)) {
                        ?><option value="<?php echo $dp['productcode'] ?>"><?php echo $dp['productcode']; ?></option><?php } ?></select></td>

<td><input type="text" id="brandss" name="brand[]" placeholder="Brand" class="form-control name_list" required  value=""></td>
```

The value will POST in ff.php

```
<?php
 require_once("conn.php");


 $id = $_POST['productid'];

     $query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT productbrand FROM products WHERE productid = '$id' ");

     while($rs = mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
     $brand = $rs['productbrand'];
}
 echo $brand;
?>
```

The problem is, Im getting the POST value but it doesn't show any output in the textfield "brand".

Comment: Try using `$("#brandss").val(data);` instead. Also, you can remove the `input` element in `ff.php`, just `echo $brand;`

Comment: Don’t use `.html()` on `input` fields. The purpose of this method is to change the content encapsulated between an element’s starting and ending tag - but input fields as stand-alone element don’t _have_ that to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

In ff.php so many PHP open and close tags. try like below and let me know

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script>
  function getState(val) {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ff.php",
    dataType:"text",
    data:{productid:val},
    success: function(data){
      $("#brandss").val(data);
    }
    });
  }
  </script>


<td><select name="drpcode" onchange="getState(this.value)" class="form-control name_list"><?php $drp = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT productcode FROM products"); while ($dp = mysqli_fetch_array($drp)) {
                        ?><option value="<?php echo $dp['productcode'] ?>"><?php echo $dp['productcode']; ?></option><?php } ?></select></td>

<td><input type="text" id="brandss" name="brand" placeholder="Brand" class="form-control name_list" required  value=""></td>
```

ff.php

```
   <?php
    require_once("conn.php");
    //$db_handle = new DBController();
       $id = $_POST['productid'];

        $query ="SELECT productbrand FROM products WHERE productid =$id";
        $results = $conn->query($query);
        while($rs=$results->fetch_assoc()) {
        $brand = $rs['productbrand'];

    }
    echo $brand;

?>
```

Comment: in ff.php the while($rs=$results->fetch_assoc()) are not returning any rows,when im selecting a value from dropdown im getting this error:  <br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: brand in <b>E:\xampp\htdocs\admin\ff.php</b> on line <b>12</b><br />

Comment: can you plz test with manual id in ff.php as I want to know the exact error location

Comment: the codes in ff.php and the output in prs.php are working when i set id manually in ff.php

$id = $_POST['productid'];

        $query ="SELECT productbrand FROM products WHERE productid ='4' ";
        $results = $conn->query($query);
        while($rs=$results->fetch_assoc()) {
        $brand = $rs['productbrand'];

    }
    echo $brand;

Comment: then just add ' ' in $id  like this "SELECT productbrand FROM products WHERE productid = '$id' ";

Comment: i did but this is the error that shows. 

<br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: brand in <b>E:\xampp\htdocs\admin\ff.php</b> on line <b>13</b><br />

Comment: can you plz edit your full code prs.php and ff.php ?

Comment: im getting a warning about extended discussions in comments, anyway done editing my code. Still getting undefined variable in ff.php

Comment: have you tried my js function? looks like you have asked a new question