# Not Getting a POST value from ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I have a select dropdown and a textfield in my form. So i tried using $.ajax whenever i choose a value in dropdown, the textfield will show an output based on the selected value from the dropdown. But im always getting an error undefined variable from ff.php. I tried to pin down the cause, and what i found is im not getting any POST value in ff.php. Any solution for this ? Thanks in advance.

Here is my code in prs.php

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script>
  function getState(val) {
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ff.php",
        data:'productid='+val,
        success: function(data){
            $("#brandss").val(data);
        }
        });
    }
  </script>

<td><select name="drpcode" onchange="getState(this.value)" class="form-control name_list"><?php $drp = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT productcode FROM products"); while ($dp = mysqli_fetch_array($drp)) {
                      ?><option value="<?php echo $dp['productid']; ?>"><?php echo $dp['productcode']; ?></option><?php } ?></select></td>

<td><input type="text" id="brandss" name="brand" placeholder="Brand" class="form-control name_list" required  value=""></td>
```

Here my codes in ff.php

```
<?php
     require_once("conn.php");


     $id = $_POST['productid'];

         $query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT productbrand FROM products WHERE productid = '$id' ");

         while($rs = mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
         $brand = $rs['productbrand'];

 }
 echo $brand;
?>
```

Comment: Is your ajax request responding? Does it work correctly? Also, can you check the variable `$brand` with `var_dump($brand);`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto fill up text fields based on selected value in dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58930799/auto-fill-up-text-fields-based-on-selected-value-in-dropdown)

Comment: you should remove echo $id in ff.php

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the format of ajax data attribute is wrong . You should try this :
`data:{productid:val}`

UPDATE :

you should select both productid and product code in select statement

```
<td>
<select name="drpcode" onchange="getState(this.value)" class="form-control 
name_list">
<?php $drp = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT productid,productcode FROM 
 products"); 
 while ($dp = mysqli_fetch_array($drp)) {
    ?><option value="<?php echo $dp['productid']; ?>"><?php echo 
  $dp['productcode']; ?></option><?php } ?>
</select>
</td>

 function getState(val) {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ff.php",
    data:{productid:val},
    success: function(data){
        $("#brandss").val(data);
    }
    });
}
```

Comment: You are only selecting productcode in your sql statement : $drp = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT productcode FROM products")  -- You are not selecting productid

Answer (score 3):

Please add the data in json format and specify the datatype as json in ajax function

```
$.ajax({
        url: "ff.php",
        type: "POST",
        data:  {
                productid : val
                // more fields can be added here
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(return){              
            // process success 
        },
        error: function(err) {
            // Process failure
        }           
});
```

Comment: How is this going to help? `data` as a plain string is perfectly valid, and `dataType` refers to the data returned from the server, so will have no effect on OPs problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the query before `select` and then display result with loop-

```
<?php $drp = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT productcode FROM products"); ?>

<select name="drpcode" onchange="getState(this.value)" class="form-control name_list"> 
<?php while ($dp = mysqli_fetch_array($drp)) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $dp['productid']; ?>"><?php echo $dp['productcode']; ?> 
    </option><?php } ?>
</select>
```